# Bug computing a Polygon area?

Tags: regions, polygons, version-11.3

Why the following code works:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {10, 10}, {5, 10}, {0, 
    10}, {0, 5}, {0, 0}};
Show[ListPlot[points], Graphics[Line[points]]]
Area[Polygon[points]]
```

And the following return nothing?

```
points2 = {{0, 0}, {5, 5}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {10, 10}, {5, 10}, {0, 
    10}, {0, 5}, {0, 0}};
Show[ListPlot[points2], Graphics[Line[points2]]]
Area[Polygon[points2]]
```

Comment: It returns 75 when I execute the second piece of code.

Comment: I'm in version 11.3 in Linux...

Comment: it returns `Area[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {5, 5}, {10, 0}, {10, 5}, {10, 10}, {5, 10}, {0,
     10}, {0, 5}, {0, 0}}]]`

Comment: Must be a version issue.  I am using `$Version=12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)`.

Comment: also returns 75 for me on `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)`

Comment: I also get an error on `"11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017)"`

Comment: Both ``Area`` and ``Polygon`` have been [updated](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn12.html) in version 12 so to me, this looks like a V11 bug.